# How to redirect to thank you page after woocommerce checkout order processed

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

im trying to change order status to "completed" and skip payment page (go to thank you page) after order is processed.

so far i manage to change order status to completed but instead of redirecting me to thank you page, i will be redirected to payment page with the following error :

[image]

this is the code i use :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed' , 'skip_join_payment' );
function skip_join_payment( $order_id ) {
     if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }
    if( $_COOKIE['isjoinForFree'] == "yes" ){
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );

        ** i tried to redirect here but getting error on checkout page **
        // if ( $order->has_status( 'completed' ) ) {
                // header("Location: /jtnx/");
                // die();
        // } 


    }
}
```

in addition i tried adding another hooks with redirect :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'skiped_join_payment_redirect', 1 ); 
function skiped_join_payment_redirect ( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if( $_COOKIE['isjoinForFree'] == "yes" ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if ( $order->has_status( 'completed' ) ) {
            header("Location: /jtnx/");
            die();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone step into this error that was my fix.
the reason for the redirect fail occur cause of the checkout ajax still running,
i added this code into my function.php, works well.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'joined_for_free_redirect_to_thankyou' );
    function joined_for_free_redirect_to_thankyou(){
        if( !is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' )) {
            return;
        }
        
        global $wp;
        $order_id =  intval( str_replace( 'join/order-pay/', '', $wp->request ) );
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        if ( $order->has_status( 'completed' ) && $_COOKIE['isjoinForFree'] == "yes" ) {
            wp_redirect( site_url() . '/jtnx/' );
            exit;
        } 
    }
```

if anyone think he has a better way to fix it i will still be happy to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

try steps below:

1. use absolute, full target page address in `header` like
   `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');`. See [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for the reason.
2. Ensure that `if( $_COOKIE['isjoinForFree'] == "yes" ) {` is true.
3. If you need, insert the `else {` part of `if( $_COOKIE['isjoinForFree'] == "yes" ) {` loop

Comment: i have tried those steps, the issue is the redirect will cause an error cause it's getting called while the ajax still runing